# snakemake multiple parameters for multiple input and single output in snakemake. ConbineGVCFs gatk problem

Tags: python, snakemake, gatk

I have written a rule for CombineGVCFs in gatk4. The rule is as follow

```
all_gvcf = get_all_gvcf_list()

rule cohort:
  input:
    all_gvcf_list = all_gvcf,
    ref="/data/refgenome/hg38.fa",
    interval_list = prefix+"/bedfiles/hg38.interval_list",
  params:
    extra = "--variant",
  output:
    prefix+"/vcf/cohort.g.vcf",
  shell:
    "gatk CombineGVCFs -R {input.ref} {params.extra} {input.all_gvcf_list} -O {output} --tmp-dir=/data/tmp -L {input.interval_list}"
```

all_gvcf is the dataset for all gvcf files which will be combined. But the problem is I need to add --variant parameter before every input. Command I'm getting right now is as follows

```
gatk CombineGVCFs -R /data/refgenome/hg38.fa --variant /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165216_HC.g.vcf /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165217_HC.g.vcf /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165218_HC.g.vcf /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165219_HC.g.vcf -O /data/prjna644607/vcf/cohort.g.vcf --tmp-dir=/data/tmp -L /data/prjna644607/bedfiles/hg38.interval_list
```

The command I want to achieve is as follows

```
gatk CombineGVCFs -R /data/refgenome/hg38.fa --variant /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165216_HC.g.vcf --variant /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165217_HC.g.vcf --variant /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165218_HC.g.vcf --variant /data/prjna644607/vcf/SRR12165219_HC.g.vcf -O /data/prjna644607/vcf/cohort.g.vcf --tmp-dir=/data/tmp -L /data/prjna644607/bedfiles/hg38.interval_list
```

How can I add this extra "--variant" tag before every input? I have added it in the get_all_gvcf_list() function. But then snakmake gives me inputfiles not found problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out the problem. Turns out I can write a lambda function as follows

```
params:
        extra=lambda wildcards, input: ' -V '.join(input.all_gvcf_list)
```

and add '-V' before {params.extra} in the "shell" sction. That solves the problem

Comment: i am facing a similar issue can you please paste the whole code for your solution?

Comment: That is the whole rule/code actually.  get_all_gvcf_list() will give the absolute path of the files in a dataset. You just need to see if the problem really matches with you. If u still need any more help then maybe you can write the entire problem and tag the question with me.

Answer (score -1):

well I came up with the solution. I think it is a little unconventional.

```
    rule gatk_CombineGVCFs:                                                 
    
        input:
            vcf_dummy = expand("gvcf/{sample}.g.vcf.gz", sample = SAMPLES), # a dummy vcf to connect this rule to gatk_HaplotypeCaller
            fa = "data/genome.fa",
    
        output:
            gvcf = "gvcf_combined/all.g.vcf.gz",
            #index = directory("gvcf_index")                                 #index generated without seperate output
        params:
            list = "gvcfs.list"
            log: "logs/CombineGVCFs.log"
        shell:
            "ls gvcf/*.gz > gvcfs.list && gatk --java-options -Xmx7g CombineGVCFs -R {input.fa} --variant {params.list} -O {output.gvcf} "   
             #Two bash comands running sequentially to make a gvcf.list as during my testing the combineGVCFs tool takes lists as input.
```

Comment: You came up with *a* solution, not *the* solution (by your own admission).

Comment: The solution to your problem should be described elaborately. Either describe your answer elaborately else add your question separately and then answer

Comment: The comments in the code describe the solution pretty elaborately. The problem was in executing the the combineGVCF to which my solution was to add  --variant in the shell and first make a list of vcfs with ls and pass it as a list to combineGVCF.